# Imrove code in async function to meet ES15 standards

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have this in an `async` function:

```
const result = knexnest(customerProducts).then(data => data);
  return result;
```

Should it be changed to this:

```
const result = await knexnest(customerProducts);
  return result;
```

Comment: Just return the call? `return knexnest(customerProducts)`

Comment: Doesn't matter. Both do the same (as long as there is not `try ... catch` around. Also `.then(data => data)` is useless.

Comment: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Do you mean ES2015 (aka ES6)?